# IMFTransfomer::ProcessInput() and MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, ms-media-foundation, aac

I have code that decodes AAC-encoded audio using IMFTransform. It works well for various test inputs. But I observed that in some cases IMFTransform::ProcessOutput() returns MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT when according to my reading of [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mftransform/ne-mftransform-_mft_output_data_buffer_flags) it should return a valid data sample.

Basically the code has the following structure:

```
IMFTransform* transformer;
MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER output_data_buffer;
...
bool try_to_get_output = false;
for (;;) {
  if (try_to_get_output) {
    // Try to get the outpu sample.
    try_to_get_output  = false;
    output_data_buffer.dwStatus = 0;
    ...
    hr = transformer->ProcessOutput(...&output_data_buffer);
    if (success) {
      // process sample
      if (output_data_buffer.dwStatus & MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER_INCOMPLETE) {
        // We have more data
        try_to_get_output  = true;
      }
    } else if (hr == MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT) {
      Log("Unnecessary ProcessOutput()");
    } else {
      // Process other errors
    }
    continue;
  }
  // Send more encoded AAC data to MFT.
  hr->ProcessInput();
}
```

What happens is that `ProcessOutput()` sets `MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER_INCOMPLETE` in `MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER.dwStatus` but then the following `ProcessOutput()` always returns `MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT` contradicting the documentation.

Again, so far it seems harmless and things works. But then what exactly does AAC decoder want to tell the caller via setting `MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER_INCOMPLETE`?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a small glitch in the decoder implementation. Quite possible that if you happen to drain the MFT it would spit out some data, so the incompletion flag migth indicate, a bit confusingly, some data even though not immediately accessible.

However overall the idea is to do `ProcessOutput` sucking the output data for as long as possible until yщu get `MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT`, and then proceed with feeding new input (or draining). That is, I would say `MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT` is much more important compared to `MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER_INCOMPLETE`. After all this is what Microsoft's own code over MFTs does.

Also keep in mind that AAC decoder is an "old", "first generation" MFT and so over years its update could be such that it diverted a bit from the current docs.

Comment: Thanks for the insight about the draining! As a test I sent the drain message to MFT after the incomplete flag and indeed it returned more data without ProcessInput() calls. And then the flag was not set. So it is indeed a glitch in the transformer. I will just ignore the flag and call ProcessOutput() until MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT